# How to plot square waveform from table

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a table:

```py
 table=[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

How to plot this table like square wave using Python? 
I would like to get effect like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be wise to include it in your post

Comment: `plt.plot(table, drawstyle='step')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang should be `'steps'`, not `'step'`, e.g. `plt.plot(table, drawstyle='steps')`, obviously after some `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.